# How can I use a for loop with array for select options?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to create a form select statement with options created with this loop like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputType" class="col-md-4 control-label">Type: <span class="error">*</span></label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <select class="form-control" name="type" id="inputType">            
                <option value="" >Select:</option>
                <?php 
                for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
                echo '< option value= ' . '"' .$result[$row][1] . '"'; 
                if ($type == $result[$row][1] ){
                     echo ' selected '; 
                }            
                echo '>' . $result[$row][1] . '< /option ><br>';
                }
                ?> 
            </select><span class="error"><?=$typeErr;?></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

If I use the exact loop after my PDO select statement, but above the html `<head>` tag:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ptype.* FROM ptype"); 
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();


            for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
            echo '< option value= ' . '"' .$result[$row][1] . '"'; 
            if ($type == $result[$row][1] ){
                 echo ' selected '; 
            }            
            echo '>' . $result[$row][1] . '< /option ><br>';
            }
```

It outputs perfectly, like this:

```
< option value= "member">member< /option >
< option value= "org employee">org employee< /option >
< option value= "org admin employee">org admin employee< /option >
< option value= "org admin member">org admin member< /option >
```

But within the form, I get nada in my select field's drop down. I had it working somewhat. It was populating the dropdown, but it was giving me the wrong values. Since I've tried to fix it, I can't get anything in the field.

This is driving me nuts!

Comment: You can have a space in the tag. Change `< option` to `<option`

Comment: Doh! My head is hurting from banging it on my desk. Thank you soooo much!!!

Comment: I had a space in the closing option tag too. It is all working now.  I can't believe how fast you answered, much less with the solution! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the space between the open tag and its name

```
echo '<option value= '
```

And again for closing tags

```
echo '>' . $result[$row][1] . '</option ><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php 
   for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
   ?>
      <option value='<?php echo $result[$row][1]; ?>' <?php if ($type == $result[$row][1] ){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
         <?php echo $result[$row][1]; ?> 
      </option>
   <?php
   }
?>
```

It will work perfectly as your requirement.
Thanks